# Go complains of wrong type when using modified version of dependency

Tags: go, dependency-management

I'm using `dep` to manage dependencies in my Go project.

I have a simple project in `~/go/src/github.com/my-repo/myproject`, with one file `example.go`:

```
package main

import (
    tcrypto "github.com/tendermint/go-crypto"
    "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/types"
)

type ExampleSigner struct{}

// Implements types.Signer
func (signer ExampleSigner) Sign(msg []byte) tcrypto.Signature {
    return tcrypto.Signature{}
}

// Implements types.Signer
func (signer ExampleSigner) PubKey() tcrypto.PubKey {
    return tcrypto.PubKey{}
}

func main() {
    mySigner := ExampleSigner{}
    validator := types.LoadPrivValidator("foo")
    validator.SetSigner(mySigner)
}
```

Running `dep init`, then `dep ensure`, then `go install` works fine. (Running the code won't do anything meaningful - this is just enough code to reproduce the compilation error below).

Now, I want to use a modified version of [`github.com/tendermint/tendermint`](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint), so per [the documentation](https://github.com/golang/dep#testing-changes-to-a-dependency), I've removed the directory from `./vendor` and have a modified copy in my `$GOPATH`:

```
~/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tendermint    <---- (modified copy)
~/go/src/github.com/my-repo/myproject/vendor/github.com/tendermint/tendermint
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
                                                          (I deleted this directory)
```

I now get the following compilation errors, assuming I've installed the `tendermint/tendermint` dependencies using `glide install`:

```
# github.com/my-repo/myproject
./example.go:25:21: cannot use mySigner (type ExampleSigner) as type "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/types".Signer in argument to validator.SetSigner:
    ExampleSigner does not implement "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/types".Signer (wrong type for PubKey method)
        have PubKey() "github.com/my-repo/myproject/vendor/github.com/tendermint/go-crypto".PubKey
        want PubKey() "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/vendor/github.com/tendermint/go-crypto".PubKey
```

If I delete the `~/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tendermint/vendor` directory, I then get these errors instead:

```
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/events.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/abci/types" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/abci/types (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/abci/types (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/genesis.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/go-crypto" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-crypto (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-crypto (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/block.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/go-wire" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-wire (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-wire (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/block.go:12:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/go-wire/data" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-wire/data (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/go-wire/data (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/block.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/common" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/common (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/common (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/events.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/events" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/events (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/events (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/priv_validator.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/log" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/log (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/log (from $GOPATH)
../../tendermint/tendermint/types/block.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/merkle" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/merkle (from $GOROOT)
    /home/djones/go/src/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/merkle (from $GOPATH)
```

Is there any way to avoid these errors, without having to commit my modified `tendermint/tendermint` to a repo somewhere and use `source` in my `Gopkg.toml`?

Comment: `github.com/my-repo/myproject` and `github.com/tendermint/tendermint` are different paths. You need to keep the import path the same to share the code between multiple packages.

Comment: @JimB In both projects, the import used is `"github.com/tendermint/go-crypto"`. I'll try and create a SSCE to demonstrate...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The `tendermint` package has a vendor directory -- libraries can't really have vendor folders, which is why they are stripped out by vendoring tools. You can either remove the vendor directory for testing, or vendor your new version into your project.

Comment: @JimB I've tried with and without the vendor folder in the `tendermint` package. With the folder in place, I get the errors in this question. Without the folder in place, I get countless build errors for packages that are vendored in *my* project. A lovely mess :-)

Comment: Yeah, this get kind of hairy with lots of complex deps ;) while it works in simple cases to get rid of `./vendor`, in general I test changes to a dependency in isolation (e.g. the "unit" tests), and test the integration by vendoring the changes back into the dependent project.

Comment: @JimB If it helps, I've updated with a compilable example. There doesn't seem to be a neat answer to this, yet presumably it's a common enough requirement...

Comment: Yes, if you remove the entire `vendor/` directory, you're going to have to have all those packages somewhere else, which means in your GOPATH (and checked out at compatible commits), and you need to watch out for separate vendor directories in each package. Yes, you need to commit your changes for a vendor tool to pick them up, but that only needs to be local. For small changes I'll often first test by modifying the vendored code directly to skip the step of updating the vendor tree.